# Problem in loading data from WebApi to Angular 8

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, swagger

I have a problem at the time of visualizing the data that a method of a `WebApi` throws at me, I am using `C#` and `Angular 8`. At the moment of trying the method in **Swagger** he throws the results fast maximum **0.2 seconds** which is fine.

But when I run my front and try to visualize it takes too long.

These are the methods:

Service that consumes the API:

```
  GetCiudad(filtro) {
    this.url = this.envirment.Url + '/GetCiudad?filtro=' + filtro;
    return this._http.get(this.url).pipe(map(res => res.json()));
  }
```

Method I use to display the data:

```
  GetCiudad() {
    this.clientesGetListService.GetCiudad('C').subscribe(
      result => {
        this.openChildServicio.dataCiudad = result;
        this.dataCiudad = result;
        this.loading = false;
      },
      error => {
        const errorMessage = <any>error;
        this.notif.error('Error', errorMessage, ConfiguracionNotificacion.configRightTopNoClose);
        console.log(errorMessage);
      }
    );
  }
```

The loading of this method in the browser console in `Network` throws me a delay of more than **10 seconds** has come to last 15 seconds, which is worrying.
Could someone help me that I am doing wrong or how I could change the consultation or the service so that it does not take so long.

Comment: Are you behind a proxy?

Comment: @Dino No we don't have a proxy, we have distributed areas with dedicated channels.